# Get color from extension

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to easly store colors, like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func color(hexString: UIColor) -> UIColor {
        switch color {
        case .light :
            return UIColor.white
        case .dark :
            return UIColor.black
        }
    }
}
```

So I can do something like `cell.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.dark` in a `if` statement. But the `.light` and `.dark` gives me this error:

> Pattern cannot match values of type '(UIColor) -> UIColor'

Ant tips?

Comment: What is `color`? Why don't you use the `hexString` parameter? Where are `.light` and `.dark` declared?

Comment: @rmaddy I am trying to learn using extensions. Point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1):

You could add extensions like this...

```
extension UIColor {
    static let light = UIColor.white
    static let dark = UIColor.black
}
```

And then access them like...

```
UIColor.light
```

And

```
UIColor.dark
```